# How can I login through 'https' login page using python3.4?

Tags: python, ssl, web-crawler, python-requests

I'm trying to login certain page with python3.4 requests, bs4 module.
When I'm trying to login with below code, ssl errors occurs :

```
import requests

userid = "myid"
password = "mypassword"

loginURL = "https://example.com/member/login"
params = {'userid': userid, 'password':password}
res = requests.post(loginURL, params=params, verify=True)
```

Errors:

```
choejeong-us-MacBook-Pro:Desktop kris$ python a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 782, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 250, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 285, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 365, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 583, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 810, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 588, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 10, in <module>
    res = requests.post(loginURL, params=params, verify=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 109, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 433, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)
```

How can I login the site with ssl page?.

I'm looked some books about python requests module and web scraping, there are no books dealing this problem.

p.s I wonder if python is really strong enough to deal with 'all' web pages ? I mean, Can I crawl all sites in the web? or there are some limitations?

Comment: Is this exception happening for all SSL servers, or just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of the traceback tells you why:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)
```

`requests` failed to verify the server's SSL certificate. You can disable cert verification with the `verify` option:

```
res = requests.post(loginURL, params=params, verify=False)
```

There are security implications in doing this, so whether you should do that is a matter for you to decide based on your application's requirements.